# Emotion-Theming and Typescript requires `theme` prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I have a styled component defined as:

```
export const Header = styled('header')`
  grid-area: header;
  border-top:solid 3px ${(props) => {
    return props.theme.colors.primary
  }};
`
```

This is then used as:

```
<Header>FOO</Header>
```

in another component.

The problem I'm having with Typescript is that by using `props.theme` in the styled component it now requires the `theme` prop be passed when `Header` is used. This is not the case in practice as `props.theme` comes from the `ThemeProvider` in use highed in the App structure.

How do I make the theme prop optional?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your interface somewhere, you can mark it optional with a questionmark:

```
interface Props {
    theme?: object; //Or whatever type it is
}
```

Comment: I'm not definining the interface for the props, emotions typings are inferring the type from the usage.